# Extracting values from JSON iOS

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json

I am developing a App which communicates with my own server (Apache->PHP) and I am sending a simple JSON Dictionary with the PHP code from the server to the App:

```
$aJSON = array('Result' => TRUE, 'Result_Msg' => "Success!!!");
echo json_encode($aJSON);
```

With these lines of code I want to extract the the values from the keys: 'Result' and 'Result_Msg':

```
// Logging the received and converted JSON/NSMutableDictionary
NSLog(@"responseDict=%@",dJSON);

BOOL b = [dJSON objectForKey:@"Response"];
NSString *string = [dJSON objectForKey:@"Result_Msg"];

NSLog(@"%@", [dJSON objectForKey:@"Response_Msg"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [dJSON valueForKey:@"Response_Msg"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [dJSON valueForKey:@"Response"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [dJSON objectForKey:@"Response"]);
```

And my printed/ logged JSON result looks like this:

> responseDict = {
>       Result = 1;
>       "Result_Msg" = "User was successfully added. Please verify your mail address."; }

Unfortunately every NSLog as well as the variables "b" and "string" are equal to (null).

Moreover I am a bit confused about the two different kind of keys like Result is without quotes ("") but Result_Msg is in quotes.

Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

The variable "dJSON" is already a NSDictionary (/MutableDic). I am doing this with these lines:

```
NSError *errorJson=nil;
    NSMutableDictionary* dJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData options:kNilOptions error:&errorJson];
if (error)
{
    UIAlertView *alert ....
    return;
}
```

// --- Analysing and extracting the values --- //

Comment: Is that really JSON generated by PHP:json_encode() ? As PHP's JSON REQUIRES all keys and values encapsulated in quotes. Also, that alone ";" at the end is fishy. Anyway, as a first step, try editing your JSON to this format: {"Result"="1";"Result_Msg"="foo"}

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I changed the PHP Code like you said but on the clients side I just got the same response like before: 
responseDict={
    Result = 1;
    "Result_Msg" = "Success!!!";
}

Comment: Then something is crippling your JSON string on the way. I am sorry I can't help you anymore, as objective-c is not my field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it...
It was like the most stupid and time-killing mistake I have had... I used the wrong keys in order to extract the values from the dictionary!!! It is not Response_Msg and Response, it is Result and Result_Msg.... it just looks the same on the first sight.

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

There is two simple ways to retreive a dictionary from your PHP code.

The first, where you don't have to change your calls to your server in your objective-c code is to use this function :

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromJSONData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *dictionaryParsed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                 options:0
                                                                   error:&error];
    if (!dictionaryParsed)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error parsing dictionary");
        }
        return nil;
    }
    return dictionaryParsed;
}
```

The second is to use the [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library, which,  by the way, provide a lot of useful stuff. (Look at `AFHTTPRequestOperation` in your case)

**EDIT**

Then, you can retrieve a bollean with :

```
BOOL myBool = [[myDictionary valueForKey:@"myKey"] boolValue];
```

And your string with :

```
NSString *myString = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that before..  of course I did the conversion before. So the variable "dJSON" is already a NSDictionary!

Comment: And do you see the correct values in your dictionary when adding a breakpoint in your code at those lines?

Comment: Yes, there are the usual key/value pairs like key:Result value:1; key:Result_Msg value:Success!!!

Comment: Try the edit I've made in my post. You should not be able to NSLog a bool with %@, but it looks weird for the string... Moreover, Result is printed without " because it is a string without any spaces